# Trying to graph SIR model with time delay element

Tags: python, delay, differential-equations

I'm ussing ddeint to try solve an SIR Model equation with a time delay. I've already successfully graphed it as an ODE but when trying to add time delay to the system I get either a wrong graph or some kind of error. Here's my code so far for the DDE version:

```
import numpy as np
pip install ddeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact
import pylab as p
from pylab import *
import math
from ddeint import ddeint

N=1000
beta = 0.3
gamma = 1/10
I0 = 1
R0 = 0
S0 = N - I0 - R0
t= np.linspace(0,160,160)
g = lambda t : array([1000,0.3,0.1])
def model(Y, t):
    S, I, R = Y(t)
    Is = Y(t-10)
    Im = Y(t-2)
    dSdt = -beta*S*Is/N + gamma*Im
    dIdt = beta*S*Is/N - gamma*I
    dRdt = gamma*I
    return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt

Y0 = S0, I0, R0
ret = ddeint(model, Y0, t)
S, I, R = ret.T
```

This is my code for the equation ( with ddeint from pip install ddeint imported). I didn't include the graph code because I know that works, I'm going wrong somewhere in the formula I think. I tried using the g for intial conditions but it gives me the wrong graph.

Comment: What exactly is the error, that your initial history is not a function, that the single derivatives are not scalars, that the derivatives object is not a flat array or does not have the format of the state vector, ...?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm getting tuple object not callable from the second last line when I try to call my initial conditions

Comment: @LutzLehmann when I use g instead of Y0 to represent a function for initial conditions (values 1000, 1, 0) the code works and I get a graph but its the wrong shape

Comment: If you do `Is = Y(t-10)`, what shape is Is and is that the expected one?

Comment: I have Is = Y(t-10) and the shape I'm meant to have is https://imgur.com/a/YF4IQJA which is like a regular SIR but with oscillations. What I get instead is https://imgur.com/a/9Z7a5o9

Comment: No, I mean shape as array. I would expect it to be to have size 3, which would give the return value a strange structure. // Also, the values of `g` are not the same as `Y0`, is this intentional? And then again none are the values in the cited image. Also, the dynamic in the image has to be different, your `R` can not be periodic.